# how to clear the stdin stream

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

 void keep_window_open()
{   
    cin.clear();        //clear badbit flag
    cin.sync();        //clear stdin stream

    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    cout <<ch <<endl;
    return;
}

int main()  
try{
    vector<int> v;
    int x;

    while(cin>>x) 
    {
        v.push_back(x);
    }   
    for(int i=0;i<=v.size();i++)
        cout<<"v["<<i<<"]=="<<v.at(i)<<endl;    //out of range

}catch (exception& oor) {
   cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << endl;
    keep_window_open();
    return 1;   
}catch(...){         
    cerr<<"exception :something went wrong\n";
    return 2;
}
```

the code above is to practice the C++ exception handler function.

However, the program couldn't run correctly at clearing stdin stream point under Ubuntu 11.04, but function well under Windows in Codeblocks . What's wrong?

Besides, why "fflush(stdin);" couldn't substitude "cin.clear(); cin.sync();"? And if there are other methods to clear streams?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I don't think there exists a good, let alone portable way to "clear" STDIN, except for reading all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this FAQ entry

http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351

**Why fflush(stdin) is wrong**

and this

http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392

**Flush the input buffer**

Comment: do you know why my code would run correctly under Windows in Codeblocks, but run wrongly under Linux, both use GNU GCC compiler? the problem confuses me for a long time. thanks for your help!

Comment: @city, In case you're still wondering, I strongly believe it's due to calling `cin.sync()`. That function is not guaranteed to do what it says, and I don't think it does on Linux. Unfortunately, I know of no better well-defined way that doesn't involve knowing whether there is something in there already or not.