# Confused about why this main isn't working

Tags: c++

Ok, so I'm trying to write a main where it will ask the user to enter a number 1 through 6 and if the number is 6 it will end the program. if it is higher than 6, it will ask to re-enter the number. The thing is, when I run it, it doesn't check the "if" statements and automatically goes to this line "please enter another option"

any thoughts why my program would do something like this?

UPDATE: I'm saying that it automatically skips all of the `if` statements and asks the last question in the `while` loop.

```
int main()
{
    int userChoice = 0;

    print(); //printing all of the options.

    cout << "Please enter one of the options listed below" <<endl;
    cin >> userChoice;

    while(userChoice != 6)// 6 = the user wishing the end the program when they press 6.
    {
        if(userChoice == 1) //adding integer to the front of the list
        {
            addValueFront();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 2)//adding integer to the back of the list
        {
            addValueBack();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 3)//removing from the list
        {
            int n = 0;
            cout << "Please enter the integer you wish to remove" << endl;
            cin >> n;
            removeValue(n);
        }
        else if(userChoice == 4)//printing the list
        {
            printList();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 5)//printing the number of items from the list
        {
            printItem();
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "The number you have entered is too high. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userChoice;
        }
        cout << "please enter another option" <<endl;

        cin >> userChoice; //sets up which option the user can choose from.
    }
}
```

Comment: The title isn't too descriptive.

Comment: Define "not working". I bet it is working and does exactly what the code there tells it to do.

Comment: Did you mean `while(userChoice != 6)`?

Comment: The code formatting needs some work

Comment: This block appears to be fine. Also, `switch-case` is better suited to your needs here.

Comment: You will double-prompt on a bad input value due to the `cin >> userChoice;` in both your tail-else block and immediately after it, if that is what you're referring to.

Comment: @chris - It is the Gas main! - He has not paid the bill!

Comment: `print();`?!? If you used self-descriptive names you wouldn't have to add obvious comments and later when you have to display more things you can do `printThisThatOrTheOther();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following program is what you want:

```
int main()                                                                     
{                                                                              
  int userChoice = 0;                                                         

  print(); //printing all of the options.                                      

  cout << "Please enter one of the options listed below" <<endl;                                                                                                  
  do // 6 = the user wishing the end the program when they press 6.                  
  {                                                                            
    cin >> userChoice;
    if(userChoice > 6)                                                      
    {                                                                       
      cout << "The number you have entered is too high. Please try again" << endl;
      cout << "please enter another option" <<endl;                         
    }                                                                       
    else if(userChoice == 1) //adding integer to the front of the list         
    {                                                                          
      addValueFront();                                                         
    }                                                                          
    else if(userChoice == 2)//adding integer to the back of the list           
    {
      addValueBack();                                                          
    }
    else if(userChoice == 3)//removing from the list                           
    {
      int n = 0;                                                               
      cout << "Please enter the integer you wish to remove" << endl;           
      cin >> n;                                                                
      removeValue(n);                                                          
    }                                                                          
    else if(userChoice == 4)//printing the list                                
    {                                                                          
      printList();                                                             
    }                                                                          
    else if(userChoice == 5)//printing the number of items from the list       
    {                                                                          
      printItem();                                                             
    }                                                                          
  } while(userChoice != 6);                                                    
}
```

Comment: Wow!! I forgot all about do-while loops! This is a life saver! :) Thank you!

Comment: You forgot about switch statement too :-P @booky99

Comment: I agree with Aniket. Switch statements on this kind of thing will make your work A LOT easier.

Answer (score 2):

Add a "continue" to the end of your else block.

```
cout << "The number you have entered is too high. Please try again" << endl;
cin >> userChoice;
continue;
```

Comment: +1 This has to be the most minimal change to address the OP's issue (the code has other issues, but this one line will address what I think he's asking about in this question).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986794/clearing-keyboard-buffer-in-c) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input). You need to call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() before every cin<<, to flush the keyboard buffers so that it behaves properly and consistently.

In addition, you should remove the cin from the else block because it's logically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch it would be the better option.

```
int main()
{
    int userChoice = 0;

    print(); //printing all of the options.

    cout << "Please enter one of the options listed below" <<endl;
    cin >> userChoice;

    while(1)// 6 = the user wishing the end the program when they press 6.
    {
        if(userChoice == 1) //adding integer to the front of the list
        {
            addValueFront();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 2)//adding integer to the back of the list
        {
            addValueBack();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 3)//removing from the list
        {
            int n = 0;
            cout << "Please enter the integer you wish to remove" << endl;
            cin >> n;
            removeValue(n);
        }
        else if(userChoice == 4)//printing the list
        {
            printList();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 5)//printing the number of items from the list
        {
            printItem();
        }
        else if(userChoice == 6)// 6 = the user wishing the end the program when they press 6.
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The number you have entered is too high. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userChoice;
        }
    }
}
```