# Clear buffer for keyboard

Tags: c++, linux, buffer, ncurses, getch

In function `boo()` I press a key, then the function `doSthTimeConsuming()` is called.

Now I am pressing keys during `doSthTimeConsuming()`.
Problem is that keys are buffered and in the next iteration `boo()` will already have an input.

Could I clear or disable buffering for the keyboard in `boo()` first?

```
void boo()
{
    while(1)
    {
        c = getch();

        switch(c)
        ...
        break;
    }
}

void doSthTimeConsuming()
{
    usleep(1000000);
}

int main()
{
    WINDOW* main_win = initscr();
        cbreak();
        noecho();
        keypad(main_win, TRUE);

    while(1)
    {
        boo();
        doSthTimeConsuming();
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

`EDIT:` I found a workaround but i am still looking for solution with clearing the buffer.

Comment: @bits_international It doesn't work. I think that condition c=='\n' OR c==EOF makes no sense here. Could you explain it?

Comment: I meant in this context. You can clearly see that i am using `cbreak();`. How does your code help? It doesn't work.

Comment: In this response you can find a portable way to clear the buffer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13987787/1817986

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function for this very purpose: `flushinp()`

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/flushinp.html

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem using `keypad(main_win, FALSE);` after input is received and enabling it `keypad(main_win, TRUE);` when it's needed.

```
void boo()
{
    keypad(main_win, TRUE);
    while(1)
    {
        c = getch();

        switch(c)
        ...
        break;
    }
    keypad(main_win, FALSE);
}
```