# Hotkey with LowLevelKeyboardHook - Clear buffer

Tags: winapi

I used to use the `RegisterHotkey` method but users have had issues based on their keyboard. For example, the hotkey does not work while a command prompt is focused. Or if the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> dialog is focused. The `LowLevelKeyboardHook` worked uniformly across all users.

I had an issue though with modifiers. For instance if the hotkey is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. If the user first:

1. downs the <kbd>Win</kbd>, I allow it
2. then downs the <kbd>F</kbd> key, I block it
3. if user ups the <kbd>F</kbd> key then I block it too
4. however, on up of the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, it comes through and the start menu opens

I tried blocking the <kbd>Win</kbd> key on step 4. However this causes it stays depressed in the keyboard buffer (pressing <kbd>L</kbd> for instance will lock the computer).
Is there a way to clear the keyboard buffer?
I was thinking of blocking the up, but after all keys are released, then clear the buffer.

I tried [the method from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34816810/1828637), but it didn't work:

```
#include <conio.h>
while (_kbhit()) {
    _getche();
}
```

Comment: From the documentation for the `RegisterHotKey` function: *"Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system."* Do you work for Microsoft?

Comment: Oh I know that @CodyGray I was just using it as example as it demonstrates it very well. My actual use case is with Alt as a modifier as it opens various menus/toolbars.